# Bring files then folders in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sorting

I have a document library in a SharePoint 2010 site and it contains files and folders.

Eg: some Excel, Word documents
and few folders.

How do I display the Excel and Word document first then the folders. No matter what I try to sort, the folders comes first then files.

Is there any way we can bring files first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Modify your view and apply the sort as in the image. Make sure you select the check box.

Comment: thank you. I did the same few minutes before and it worked. Thanks for the response.